Why does connection work despite specifying for it a hmac-sha1-etm MAC that is not configured on server side?
I've seen other topics regarding similar issue and while configuration seems to work fine with specified MACs, SSH connection which uses an unspecified MAC still works while I would expect it to not.
Does it work as intended and I am missing something or something's wrong in there?
Both SSH (client and server) versions are listed in the snippet along with content of custom SSH config file which restricts connections to specified MACs.
PS C:\Users\kamil> ssh -m hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com -t debian12 "ssh -V && echo --- && sudo sshd -T | egrep '^macs' && echo --- && cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/60-remove-insecure-mac.conf"
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3, OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024
---
macs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
---
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.


If your configured-or-default client preferences result in an AEAD cipher (chacha-poly or aes-gcm) being selected then no MAC is needed or used and the MAC settings are ignored

Yes, that's the case indeed. Thank you very much.

The debug output (-vvv) is showing this:
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none

Basically it means it falls back to chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com cipher which has its own implicit MAC. If you reject this cipher in the sshd configuration (or ssh on client side) by adding Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  to the config, the connection should be rejected:
Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1 port 22: no matching MAC found. Their offer: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com


-Because unfortunately the MAC ADDRESS only refers directly to a hardware device, the MAC ADDRESS does not change, ok! To solve this you would only need a software that gives you the possibility to change this address, ok! This MAC address that he did not restrict in the connection you saw must be in a previous list that helps in controlling the connections.

MAC in this context isn’t a MAC address; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code
